# Automating Scanning with Adobe Acrobat Pro 2017: Is there a shortcut key?

Tags: adobe, autohotkey, acrobat

I am trying to automate keystrokes required to perform a scan with Adobe Acrobat Pro 2017.

Unfortunately there does not seem to be a shortcut key for the "Scan" button built into the UI, nor are there a consistent number of tab keystrokes to reach this button; when you wish to append an existing scanned document, extra tab positions are created which throws it off.

Is there any other method of reaching this button that I don't know? An undocumented shortcut key combination perhaps? The only other solution I could think of would be to keep pushing tabs after a delay which adds further unreliability to an unreliable method.

Comment: You may want to consider using AutoHotkey's `ImageSearch` command if you can't find another way.

Comment: I may have to but I've found that can be quite unreliable as well, if the screen resolution changes say

Comment: The `ImageSearch` default search coordinates are relative to the active window, so I believe screen resolution changes shouldn't be a problem. I've used it in games and have had success.

Comment: I don't know why but I've had a lot of trouble with it in the office, it could be small updates to the OS or the database UI in the past have constantly thrown it off... in any case, it's left me not trusting it.

Maybe some kind of combination approach would work... hmmmm